# getContentResolver().query() android for getting images of specific width and height

Tags: android, media-queries, mediastore

getContentResolver().query() for getting images of specific width and height 
this is the normal query

```
final String[] columns = {
    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.HEIGHT
    };


Cursor mCursor = _context.getContentResolver().
                     query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                          columns,null,null,
                          MediaStore.Images.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be helpful for people looking for an answer

```
String[] projection1 = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection1, // Which columns to return
                (MediaStore.Images.Media.HEIGHT + " <= 600" + " AND "
                        + MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH + " <= 600"),       // Return all rows
                null,
                null);
```